# Java: Is it not possible to use an iterator to iterate a HashMap of objects and change attributes of objects?

Tags: java, oop, iterator

I know this may be a very basic question to the experts in here. But I cannot get my head around this. 
Basically, I have the following depth-first-search instance method. I have an object class `Dgraph`, which is `HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>>`. `Vertex` is just an object class I created and it contains a `color` attribute and a `node` attribute.

**Problem:** Basically, I want to change the color of the Vertex object within the iterator statement. But it doesn't work as expected. I was able to change the `color` attribute of each vertex object within the iterator but when I leave the iterator , the color attribute of each vertex are still `null`.

**Note that Vertex objects with same node values are the same object**, i.e. consider `5 --> 1` and `1 -- 9`, we only have one  Vertex object with node equal to `1` here.

```
public void depth_first_search(Dgraph graph){
        // for debugging
        System.out.println("Before iterator");
        System.out.println("Graph = " + graph);
        System.out.println("");
        graph.display();
    HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>> dag = graph.returnHashMap(graph);
    for(Map.Entry<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>> g_map : dag.entrySet() ){
        Vertex u = g_map.getKey();
        u.set_color("WHITE");
        System.out.println("In iterator --> Vertex u = " + u + " color = " + u.get_color());
    }
    // for debugging 
    System.out.println("*************************");
    System.out.println("After iterator");
    System.out.println("Graph = " + dag);
    graph.display();
    }
}
```

This is the debugging output I got:

```
Before iterator
Graph = Dgraph@7852e922

5 : [1, 9]
    null    null
3 : [511596]
    null
2 : [47646, 47647, 13019, 47648, 47649, 47650, 7700, 47651, 47652]
    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
1 : [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 8, 4]
    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
in iterator --> Vertex u = 5 color = WHITE
in iterator --> Vertex u = 3 color = WHITE
in iterator --> Vertex u = 2 color = WHITE
in iterator --> Vertex u = 1 color = WHITE
*************************
After iterator
Graph = {5=[1, 9], 3=[511596], 2=[47646, 47647, 13019, 47648, 47649, 47650, 7700, 47651, 47652], 1=[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 8, 4]}

5 : [1, 9]
    null    null
3 : [511596]
    null
2 : [47646, 47647, 13019, 47648, 47649, 47650, 7700, 47651, 47652]
    null    null    null    null    null        null    null   null   null
1 : [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 8, 4]
    WHITE   null        null    null    null    null    null       null
```

I removed my `toString` method, so you guys can take a look at the references and check some of them referring to the same object.

```
Before iterator
Graph = Dgraph@7852e922

Vertex@9b : [Vertex@1f, Vertex@117]
    null    null
Vertex@5d : [Vertex@f1ff14]
    null
Vertex@3e : [Vertex@1689a2, Vertex@1689c1, Vertex@62885, Vertex@1689e0, Vertex@1689ff, Vertex@168a1e, Vertex@3a46c, Vertex@168a3d, Vertex@168a5c]
    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
Vertex@1f : [Vertex@1f, Vertex@3e, Vertex@9b, Vertex@ba, Vertex@d9, Vertex@5d, Vertex@f8, Vertex@7c]
    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
in iterator --> Vertex u = Vertex@9b color = WHITE
in iterator --> Vertex u = Vertex@5d color = WHITE
in iterator --> Vertex u = Vertex@3e color = WHITE
in iterator --> Vertex u = Vertex@1f color = WHITE
*************************
After iterator
Graph = {Vertex@9b=[Vertex@1f, Vertex@117], Vertex@5d=[Vertex@f1ff14], Vertex@3e=[Vertex@1689a2, Vertex@1689c1, Vertex@62885, Vertex@1689e0, Vertex@1689ff, Vertex@168a1e, Vertex@3a46c, Vertex@168a3d, Vertex@168a5c], Vertex@1f=[Vertex@1f, Vertex@3e, Vertex@9b, Vertex@ba, Vertex@d9, Vertex@5d, Vertex@f8, Vertex@7c]}

Vertex@9b : [Vertex@1f, Vertex@117]
    null    null
Vertex@5d : [Vertex@f1ff14]
    null
Vertex@3e : [Vertex@1689a2, Vertex@1689c1, Vertex@62885, Vertex@1689e0, Vertex@1689ff, Vertex@168a1e, Vertex@3a46c, Vertex@168a3d, Vertex@168a5c]
    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
Vertex@1f : [Vertex@1f, Vertex@3e, Vertex@9b, Vertex@ba, Vertex@d9, Vertex@5d, Vertex@f8, Vertex@7c]
    WHITE   null    null    null    null    null    null    null
```

**UPDATE:** The instance method `returnHashMap` sits in the class `Dgraph` as follow:

```
class Dgraph{

    // instance variable
    HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>> dag;

    // constructor
    public Dgraph(String file, boolean reverse) throws IOException{
        dag = read_file_and_populate(file, reverse);
    }

    public HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>> returnHashMap(Dgraph g){
        return g.dag;
    }
    .....
}
```

The Vertex class is shown below:

```
class Vertex{
    private long node;
    private String color;
    private long d;
    private long pi;
    private long f;

public Vertex(long node){
    this.node = node;
}

// return color
public String get_color(){
    return color;
}

// change color
public void set_color(String color){
    this.color = color;
}

// return distance
public long get_d(){
    return d;
}

// change distance
public void set_d(long d){
    this.d = d;
}

// return predecessor
public long get_pi(){
    return pi;
}

// assign predecessor
public void set_pi(long pi){
    this.pi = pi;
}

// to String (prevent print reference)
public String toString(){
    return node+"";
}

// return node
public long get_node(){
    return node;
}

// return finishing time
public long get_f(){
    return f;
}

// set finishing time
public void set_f(long f){
    this.f = f;
}

// Need hashCode() and equals() to compare objects
 public int hashCode(){
     return (int)(node * 31);
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this){
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()){
        return false;
    }
    Vertex other = (Vertex)o;
    return node  == other.node;
}
}
```

This is the display method that I am using:

```
public void display(){
    for(Map.Entry<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>> entry : dag.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
        for(Iterator<Vertex> iterator = dag.get(entry.getKey()).iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            Vertex vv = iterator.next();
            System.out.print("\t" + vv.get_color());
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

**UPDATE** : Below is the code that I used to create the HashMap. I thought I was creating a HashMap such that if two Vertex objects with the same node value appear in the key and in the value , they would share the same memory address and point to the same Vertex Object (i.e. there should only be one Vertex Object).

```
public Vertex getVertex(Map<Long,Vertex> vertices_map, long node){
        if( ! vertices_map.containsKey(node) ) vertices_map.put(node, new Vertex(node));
        return vertices_map.get(node);
    }

    // read file and return graphs
    public HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>> read_file_and_populate(String file_loc, boolean reverse) throws IOException{

    HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>> graph = new HashMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>>();
    int l = 0;
    int r = 0;
    if(reverse == false){
        r = 1;
    } else{
        l = 1;
    }

    FileInputStream fil = new FileInputStream(file_loc);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(fil));
    String element = null;

    while( (element = br.readLine()) != null){
        String[] line = element.split("\\s");
        /*
         *
         *  Create a new vertex object when the node first occurs;
         *  And if the node occurs more than once, return a copy of the
         *  reference to the same object with the same node value.
         *
         */
        HashMap<Long, Vertex> vertices_map = new HashMap<Long, Vertex>();
        Vertex v_l = getVertex(vertices_map , Long.parseLong(line[l]) );
        Vertex v_r = getVertex(vertices_map , Long.parseLong(line[r]) );

        if(graph.containsKey(v_l) == false){
            ArrayList<Vertex> edges_of_this_vertex = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
            edges_of_this_vertex.add(v_r);
            graph.put(v_l, edges_of_this_vertex);
        } else{
            graph.get(v_l).add(v_r);
        }
    }
    return graph;
}
```

Comment: What does your returnHashMap method do?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I just updated the question and explained what the instance method `returnHashMap` does in my code. It essentially returns the HashMap of vertices (key) and arraylist of vertices (values).

Comment: show your Vertex class.

Comment: You haven't posted all the relevant code, but I suspect you're updating the keys but displaying the values.

Comment: I wanted to show you guys all the code. But it is like several hundered lines long. So, I would only show them if you ask for them. I posted the `display` method that I was using as well.

Comment: Note that the display method sits in the `Dgraph` class.

Comment: You don't need to post *all* the code: you *must* post *all* the *relevant* code. You haven't done that.

Comment: I only just realised where the source of the problem is. So I didn't know even what my relevant code was before. But I do now. So I apologise for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: I made a silly bug in my code. And it has become too long for anyone to read now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You modify the color of the *keys*, but the display method only prints the colors of the *values*.  You have one Vertex which is a key and a value ("Vertex@1f"), which is why you have the lone "WHITE" output in the bottom row of your output.

UPDATE:

Look at this line (note its placement in the code flow):

```
    HashMap<Long, Vertex> vertices_map = new HashMap<Long, Vertex>();
```

Comment: but if you look at the memory address output that I posted, for example `in the iterator  Vertex u = Vertex@3e color = WHITE`, this actually corresponds to the Vertex Object with node = 2 and it appears in the key and in the value as well. My point is that the same Vertex objects in my code can appear in the keys and in the values such that if I make any changes to a particular Vertex Object, the changes will be reflected in the entire HashMap.

Comment: why don't you try changing the `Vertex.toString()` method to include the color: `return node + " " + color;`?

Comment: Oh ! You are right!!! Why is this happening ? Only the color of the keys are changed . But I thought according to the memory address output that I posted, the reference of the key and the reference of the values are pointing to the SAME object. I am very puzzled now.

Comment: Obviously they aren't, but, again, as you have't posted the relevant code, it is impossible to help you further.

Comment: I spotted my stupid mistake now. I kept initialising the same hashmap in the while loop. Thank you very much for all your effort guys. Really appreciated your help.